# cant use vue-i18n v.9 <i18n > blocks

Tags: nuxtjs3, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I'm using nuxt 3 and [i18n v.9](https://github.com/intlify/vue-i18n-next).

I wanna to use new feature in i18n v.9 that allows you to make a  block next to

script and template block and put translates there .

like this :

```html
<template>
  {{ $t('hi') }}
</template>

<i18n>
{
    "en": {
        "hi": "hello world!"
    },
    "ja": {
        "hi": "こんにちは、世界！"
    }
}
</i18n>
```

and this is `nuxt.config.ts`

```js
import VueI18nVitePlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'
import path from 'path'
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules: [
    '@pinia/nuxt','@nuxtjs/tailwindcss' ,'@nuxt-hero-icons/outline/nuxt','@nuxt-hero-icons/solid/nuxt'
  ],
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
     captchaKey: 'a', 
      apiUrl:'z'
    }
  },
   vite: {
       plugins: [
         VueI18nVitePlugin({
           include: [
             path.resolve(__dirname, './components/*.*'),
             path.resolve(__dirname, './pages/*.*'),
           ]
         })
       ]
     }
})
```

and this is the `package.json`

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n": "^0.7.0",
    "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n": "^6.0.3",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.3.3",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.10",
    "sass": "^1.55.0",
    "sass-loader": "10.1.1",
    "tailwindcss-flip": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/vue": "^2.0.11",
    "@kyvg/vue3-notification": "^2.4.1",
    "@nuxt-hero-icons/outline": "^1.0.1",
    "@nuxt-hero-icons/solid": "^1.0.1",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.2",
    "@vueform/multiselect": "^2.5.2",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "daisyui": "^2.28.0",
    "jenesius-vue-modal": "^1.7.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.33",
    "vee-validate": "^4.6.7",
    "vue-recaptcha-v3": "^2.0.1",
    "vue3-loading-overlay": "^0.0.0",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  }
}
```

The problem is that translates doesn't come. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi, please put some effort into the formatting of your code (I've edited your question here too).

Comment: Did you tried that one? https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/migration/breaking.html#translation-component Rename the `i18n` tag towards `i18n-t` mostly.

Comment: yes , it didn't work

Comment: Please give more details. What is happening exactly? Any error in the console? Something in Vue devtools?

Comment: no there is no error , just translates is not shown

Comment: https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/sfc.html
i did like this

Comment: I'll need to try that one on my side to double check I guess.

Answer (score 3):

To use custom blocks in SFC you will need to set it up like follows

```
<script setup>
const { t } = useI18n({
  useScope: "local",
});
</script>

<template>
 <p>{{ t('hi) }}</p>
</template>

<i18n>
{
    "en": {
        "hi": "hello world!"
    },
    "ja": {
        "hi": "こんにちは、世界！"
    }
}
</i18n>
```